# How to use keys of a dictionary as a pandas dataframe column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dictionary with 20 keys and each each key has values in the form of a list of sentences translated from different languages to French. The key is what tells me the name of the language. This is why I would like to have all the dictionary keys in the first column of my dataframe.

What I want is to convert my dict to a dataframe with the dictionary keys as the index or the first column.

My code

```
for k, v in Liste_phrases_retraduit.items():
    v = [i.split("\t") for i in v]
    df = pd.DataFrame(v, columns = ['identifiant', 'verbatim', 'etiquette'] )
    print(df.head())
```

Current output:

```
    identifiant                                           verbatim  etiquette
0  identifiant                                           verbatim  etiquette
1          463  Quels problèmes ce concept résout-il ? Nous re...          M
2         2647  Cela signifie donc que pour la solution, vous ...          C
3         5391  Cela ne changera pas la qualité du produit, je...          M
4         1120  C'est très intéressant, parce que c'est un env...          M
   identifiant                                           verbatim  etiquette
0  identifiant                                           verbatim  etiquette
1          463  Quels problèmes ce concept résout-il ? Nous re...          M
2         2647  Cela signifie donc que pour le résoudre, nous ...          C
3         5391  Je ne pense pas que cela changera la qualité d...          M
4         1120  Sur les stations de pompage, c'est très intére...          M
   identifiant                                           verbatim  etiquette
0  identifiant                                           verbatim  etiquette
1          463  Quels problèmes ce concept résout-il ? Nous re...          M
2         2647  Cela signifie donc que pour la solution, vous ...          C
3         5391  Cela ne changera pas la qualité du produit, je...          M
4         1120  sur les stations de pompage, c'est très intére...          M
```

As you can see, it is the same thing but without the keys. I cannot know which sentences belong to which language. This will help me to filter the data at a later stage.

Expected output:

```
  id_langue  identifiant                                           verbatim  etiquette
0  british   identifiant                                           verbatim  etiquette
1  british        463  Quels problèmes ce concept résout-il ? Nous re...          M
2   ....          2647  Cela signifie donc que pour la solution, vous ...          C
 
0  american   identifiant                                           verbatim  etiquette
1  american       463  Quels problèmes ce concept résout-il ? Nous re...          M
2   ....          2647  Cela signifie donc que pour la solution, vous ...          C
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Simply add another column to the dataframe and put the key as the value.

```
df['id_langue'] = k
```